# How to set picture as background in python? I am only importing Graphics. No pygames or turtles

Tags: python, graphics

I checked the document for Graphics.
It says:

*Image(anchorPoint, filename)*

Constructs an image from contents of the given file, centered at the given anchor point. Can also be called with width and height parameters instead of filename. In this case, a blank (transparent) image is created of the given width and height.

But I tried to type:
window = GraphWin("game", 400, 400)

Image((200,200),"flower.png")

But it doesnt work.

Do I need to import the picture first??Or add it to the window?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally should work, you missed the **anchorPoint**

```
from graphics import *

window = GraphWin("game", 400, 400)
myimage=Image(Point(200,200),"flower.png")
myimage.draw(window)
```